# Angular 4: Output data from dynamic modal to component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, material-design

I am using material design and have a dialogService set up for dynamically loading MdDialog. I'm trying to make a search dialog with search filters that when submitted it brings you to a search-results component route. And I can't figure out how to output the search data to the search-results component.

./dialog-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
    export class DialogService {
    private dynamicModalComponent: DialogComponent;

    public init(dynModal: DialogComponent) {
        this.dynamicModalComponent = dynModal;
    }

    public show(component: Type<any>, configuration?: MdDialogConfig) {
        this.dynamicModalComponent.showModal(component, configuration);
    }

    public hide() {
        this.dynamicModalComponent.hideModal();
    }
}
```

./modules/search.component.html

```
<div class="search-component">
<h2>Search</h2>
<md-input-container class="full-width search">
    <input mdInput placeholder="search" color="primary" />
</md-input-container>
<div class="radio-groups">
    <md-radio-group class="radio-buttons" [(ngModel)]="searchFilterValue">
        <md-radio-button class="r-button" [value]="sf.value" *ngFor="let sf 
of searchFilter">
            {{sf.name}}
        </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
</div>
<md-dialog-actions class="actions">
    <button md-button (click)="hide()">Cancel</button>
    <button md-raised-button (click)="search()" 
          color="primary">Search</button>
</md-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

./modules/search.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {DialogService} from "../dialog/dialog.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
@Component({
    selector: 'search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
searchFilterValue;
searchFilter = [
    {
        name: 'Groups',
        value: 'groups',
    },
    {
        name: 'People',
        value: 'users',
    },
    {
        name: 'Events',
        value: 'events',
    },
    {
        name: 'Posts',
        value: 'posts',
    }
];
constructor(private _dialogService: DialogService,
            private router: Router){
    this.searchFilterValue = 'groups';
}

ngOnInit(){}

hide() {
    this._dialogService.hide();
}

search() {
    this.hide();
    this.router.navigate(['/search']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1) You could use optional or query routing parameters. Then as part of the `router.navigate`, you'd also pass along the parameters. This is a great option if you need to pass data from this component directly to another component.

2) Another option is to build a service. The service holds onto the search filter values. The search component sets the values into the service and the component then reads the values from the service.

Do one of these options sound like they could work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an output event for hide/close event and pass result as event argument.Other components can subscribe such event to handle result.